Issue with message filter Subscriber in combination with LifecycleNode
I'm facing a compiler problem when trying to use message_filters::Subscribers within a LifecycleNode.
Using these private class variables of my class ExampleLifeCycleNode:
  // Subscriber IMU data
  message_filters::Subscriber<sensor_msgs::msg::Imu> imuDataSubscriber_;
  message_filters::Subscriber<diagnostic_msgs::msg::DiagnosticArray>
      imuDiagnosticSubscriber_;

within i.e.the on_configure() function:
rclcpp_lifecycle::node_interfaces::LifecycleNodeInterface::CallbackReturn
NavigationFilterNode::on_configure(const rclcpp_lifecycle::State&) {

    imuDataSubscriber_ = this->create_subscription<sensor_msgs::msg::Imu>(
    "/sensors/imu", 10, [this](sensor_msgs::msg::Imu::SharedPtr msg) {})

  // Return success
  return rclcpp_lifecycle::node_interfaces::LifecycleNodeInterface::
      CallbackReturn::SUCCESS;
}

does lead to compiler error:

/usr/include/c++/11/ext/new_allocator.h:162:11: error: no matching function for call to ‘message_filters::Subscriber<std_msgs::msg::Float64_std::allocator<void > >::Subscriber(std::shared_ptrrclcpp::node_interfaces::NodeBaseInterface, const char [7], rmw_qos_profile_s&)’
162 |         { ::new((void *)__p) _Up(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...); }

I also tried to make imuDataSubscriber_ a std::shared_ptr which also does not work.
Hope you can help me with this problem or give me some advice.
Kind regards
Max
